# asp.net Live chart

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having trouble updating and formatting my chart on asp.net with data directly from sql database. The data from the database comes through, but I cant figure out how to format the x axis so that minDateTime is minimum value and maxDateTime is maximum value. The main problem though is that everytime i add X and Y values the chart just seems to replace everything else already in the chart with the new values, not add them on to the ones before.

Backcode chart (sql stuff is hidden here as this is not the problem):

```
private void Graph(int Id)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"HIDDEN HERE"))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("HIDDEN HERE", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
        }


        string[] x = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
        double[] y = new double[dt.Rows.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            y[i] = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][0]);
            x[i] = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString(); y);
            LiveChart.Series["LiveSeries"].Points.AddXY(minDateTime.Hour, 
            y.Last());
            //This works in some way but doesnt do what i want:
            //LiveChart.Series["LiveSeries"].Points.DataBindXY(x, y);

        }

        LiveChart.Series[0].XValueType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.DateTime;
        LiveChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;

        //This completely messes up my chart, but this is what i want, min value to be current hour and max value to be end of day.
        //LiveChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = minDateTime.Hour;
        //LiveChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = maxDateTime.Hour;
    }
```

The Graph() method is called in a tick event. string[] x receives datetime from sql server and double[] y receives respective values.

Declaration in Main:

```
minDateTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
maxDateTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 23, 59, 59, 999);
```

The reason I use addXY(minDateTime.Hour, y.Last()) is because i want the current Hour (Actually hour and minutes but i dont know how) to represent the last value that entered the y array. The chart binds the last y value with the current hour but it doesnt add more, meaning that every new y value will just bind with the current hour without displaying all the ones before. I know i should probably use databind but I dont know how to do it in this case. I want the last y value from the database to bind with the current hour (and minutes) every tick and add onto this so the graph fills up, unlike how it does now when it wont add new datapoints just the latest.

How do i do this?